# Транзакции mysqli

Tags: mysqli, mysql

Здравствуйте, вопрос по поводу транзакций в mysqli. А конкретнее по принципу их работы. Вот есть первый пользователь, который открыл страницу где запустилась транзакция и началось выполнение запросов. Есть второй пользователь, который открыл ту же страницу, пока выполняются запросы у первого, и началось выполнения транзакции у второго пользователя. Они будут работать паралельно или вторая начнется после того как закончится первая? Могут ли они мешать друг другу? Спасибо.

Comment: Параллельно, если движок БД позволяет синхронные подключение от одного пользователя (иначе второй пользователь будет ждать до тех пор, пока соединение не освободится; это редкая ситуация, но с месяц назад здесь проскакивала).

Comment: > Могут ли они мешать друг другу?

Мешать - нет; "область видимости" задается [уровнем изоляции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9) и определяет, какие данные видны и модифицируемы при выполнении транзакции. Точнее, могут очевидно затереть друг друга или подхватить неправильные данные при допуске со стороны уровня изоляции.